# How to prevent from an object's property from being sent and created at Backendless

Tags: java, android, server, backendless

I have object model in backendless app, the schema:

```
public class Message{

    public  String objectId;
    private long created_at;
    private String sender,receiver,text;
    public boolean isSearched;
    ...
}
```

i don't want to create the column `"isSearched"` in the database, how can i do that?

i tried to use `transient` with the implementation of `Serializable` before the public declaration:

```
public class Message implements Serializable{

  public  String objectId;
  private long created_at;
  private String sender,receiver,text;
  transient public boolean isSearched;
}
```

but still when i execute the save method like so:

```
Backendless.Persistence.save( new Message(...), new AsyncCallback<Message>())
```

the column `Searched` is created at the DB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try annotating your class with this : `@ExcludeProperty( propertyName = "isSearched" )`

Comment: Have you tried backendless? Where should i put this annotation exactly?

Comment: I know the field is public, but do you have public getter/setter methods for the field?

Answer (score 0):

Disable *Dynamic User Definition* in the console.
[image]